# Trying to check & replace the xml file used in my AIR app

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, air, adobe

I've got an app that is displaying informations to the user. These information are in an xml file, directly embbed in the app.
Each year, I have to update the information in the xml file and, therfore, I have to submit a new app update via Google Play Store and Apple Store.

I thought of a way to, maybe, avoid updating the all app.

I was thinking if the app, when starting, was checking the file size of the xml file and the file size of an xml file I'd have on a server.
If the size is identical, the file won't be download/replace.
If the size is different, the the file would be download and would replace the current xml file.

Questions :

- Even if my app is currently using and displaying the xml info, can it replace the file (maybe AIR won't allow it as it's being read by the app) ?

I've tried to do that but it doesn't work :

```
function checking_Files():void
{
    var size_of_horaires_local;
    var size_of_horaires_online;

    var url_local:URLRequest = new URLRequest("horaires3.xml");


    var url_online:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://****.vps.ovh.ca/horaires3.xml");
;
// Define the URLLoader.
    var loader_local:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    var loader_online:URLLoader = new URLLoader();



loader_local.load(url_local);
loader_online.load(url_online);
    


// Listen for when the file has finished loadingloader_local_Complete
loader_local.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loader_local_Complete);
loader_online.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loader_online_Complete);
    

function loader_local_Complete(e:Event):void
{
    // The output of the text file is available via the data property
    // of URLLoader.
     trace("size: " + (URLLoader(e.target).bytesTotal));
    size_of_horaires_local = URLLoader(e.target).bytesTotal; 
    
}



function loader_online_Complete(e:Event):void{
    // The output of the text file is available via the data property
    // of URLLoader.
     trace("size: " + (URLLoader(e.target).bytesTotal));
    size_of_horaires_online = URLLoader(e.target).bytesTotal;
    check_if_size_different();
    
}

function check_if_size_different():void{
    trace("checking if size is different");
    if(size_of_horaires_local == size_of_horaires_online){
        trace("do nothing");
        log_txt.text="Do nothing, same size. Copy File to specific path";   
        dontWait = true;
    //do nothing
    }else{
        log_txt.text="download the new xml file";
        download_the_new_xml();
        wait = true;
        log_txt.text="Récupération de données en cours...";
    }
}



function download_the_new_xml():void{
var urlString:String = "http://****.vps.ovh.ca/horaires3.xml";
var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(urlString);
var urlStream:URLStream = new URLStream();
var fileData:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
urlStream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);
urlStream.load(urlReq);

 

function loaded(event:Event):void {
urlStream.readBytes(fileData, 0, urlStream.bytesAvailable);
writeFile();
}

 

function writeFile():void {

fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
fileStream.writeBytes(fileData, 0, fileData.length);
fileStream.close();
    wait = false;
    dontWait = true;
    introFinish(null);
    //log_txt.text="The new XML file is written here : "+file.url;
    trace("The new XML file is written here : "+file.url);

}
}
```

It seems that the "path" of the new xml file is wrong. I can't find a way to write and replace the old xml that is embbed in the app.

Any ideas if it's doable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can overwrite files that were bundled into your app.

A possible solution is to write the XML to a new local XML file and save it in the documentsDirectory or appStorageDirectory and include a version number as a node.

```
public static var _xmlFile:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("yourapp.xml");

private static const _initialXML:String = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><contents><version>100</version></contents>";

//only write to local on first launch                 
if(!_xmlFile.exists){
_writeFileStream.open(_xmlFile, FileMode.WRITE);
_writeFileStream.writeUTFBytes(_initialXML);        
_writeFileStream.close();
}
```

Then whenever the app launches it loads in the local xml as well as the new xml from the server, compares the version numbers and overwrites the local version with the server version if necessary.

The app then uses the local version for its configuration.

Comment: The **File.applicationStorageDirectory** is the correct folder to store such data, because **File.documentsDirectory** can be accessed and modified by user.